# Is there a connection between LibreOffice UNO and the UNO platform?

Tags: libreoffice, uno-platform

The [UNO platform](https://platform.uno/) does not mention LibreOffice, and the LibreOffice URE (UNO Runtime Environment) does not seem to have anything to do with the UNO platform. Are they using UNO to mean different things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no link between the two products. There is also absolutely no link with the Uno cards game.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Stack Overflow `uno` tag concerns only the OOo/LO UNO Runtime Environment and shouldn't be used to tag questions about either the UNO platform or the Uno card game.